# how to highlight row & column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use VBA or conditional formatting to highlight the entire current row and column of the current cell? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sheets worksheets selection change event, you can use something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = 4

    'remove past colors
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    With Me
        .Columns(Target.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
        .Rows(Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
```

You can fill in r,g & b to achieve the highlighting color you want.

Comment: Good answer. I like using ActiveCell as opposed to Target as it highlights the cell that the person will be typing into. This really only shows up when they do a multi-cell selection. Combine this answer with the one above to get the full effect. If you use Interior.Color, you can use the vbColor constants instead of RGB values if you like. vbRed, vbGreen, vbYellow, etc. I find using these much more friendly. But if you need an exact color match, use the RGB values.