# Excel 2010 when button is pressed, highlight row

Tags: excel, vba

I have to make a database of mail addresses.

The annoying thing is to keep your eye on what you've already filled in. I would like to put in a button to highlight the entire row. How can I do this?

I used Google to search but I can't find anything that is really helpful.

I could highlight them by myself but I want them to get highlighted by just one click instead of first selecting the row and then selecting the color.

Comment: what about events?? I would suggest using `SelectionChange` and no button needed then. Right after you change selection your row will be highlighted...

Comment: What 'full' code would you recommend to make them - for example - green after changing selection? Can't find a useful one.

Comment: [this could be good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107270/how-to-highlight-row-column-in-excel) or alternatively try to examine and change [this solution](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/highlighting-the-active-row-and-column/)

Comment: Well, I have found a good one. It works now, but I want it work after pressing Enter insteed of clicking. Is this possible?

Comment: you mean after you change cell and press enter?? it should highlight changed row-use `Change` event in that situation. or after you move with enter key- this will work with `SelectionChange`

Comment: True, didn't realize that, haha. Anyway, thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Basically its this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = 65535
End Sub
```